# Conditions required for Inequality to hold

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, proof-writing, real-numbers

Given that $0 \leq X \leq x \leq y \leq Y < \infty$, I am interested to know the condition whereby $\frac{\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x}} \leq \frac{\sqrt{Y}-\sqrt{X}}{\sqrt{Y}+\sqrt{X}} $ holds.

The following is what I have got so far.

We know that $\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x} \leq \sqrt{Y}-\sqrt{X} $, so we just need the condition whereby $\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{Y}+\sqrt{X}}$.
This is equivalent to $\sqrt{Y}-\sqrt{y} \leq \sqrt{x}-\sqrt{X}$.
This is where I got stuck. I can now only say that we require $x$ to be relatively closer to $Y$ as compared to $X$ which is not mathematical at all. Can anyone help me refine this ? Or is this as far as I could go?

Comment: $$\frac{\sqrt{y} - \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{y} + \sqrt{x}} \leq \frac{\sqrt{Y} - \sqrt{X}}{\sqrt{Y} + \sqrt{X}}$$
and
$$\sqrt{y} - \sqrt{x} \leq \sqrt{Y} - \sqrt{X}$$
**does NOT** imply
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{y} + \sqrt{x}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{Y} + \sqrt{X}}.$$

Comment: Also, are $x$, $y$, $X$, and $Y$ nonnegative integers or nonnegative real numbers?

Comment: They are real numbers.

Comment: Okay, typesetting an answer now.

Comment: alright thanks.

Comment: I can see that Yves has already given an answer.

Comment: @ArnieDris: I just gave a hint, not the complete answer.

Comment: @ArnieDris Thanks for your help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$0\le X\le x\le y\le Y$$ implies $$0\le X^2\le x^2\le y^2\le Y^2$$ and you can safely ignore the square roots. Also, the fractions are homogeneous so that you can set $p:=\dfrac yx,P:=\dfrac YX$, and study

$$\frac{p-1}{p+1}\le\frac{P-1}{P+1}.$$

This function is strictly increasing in the positive arguments, so that

$$\frac yx\le\frac YX\implies \frac{\sqrt y-\sqrt x}{\sqrt y+\sqrt x}\le\frac{\sqrt Y-\sqrt X}{\sqrt Y+\sqrt X}.$$

Comment: Yves, does your conclusion still hold if $Y < 1$?

Comment: @ArnieDris: sure, the formulas only depend on ratios, not on individual values.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Alright, I get it now. Thanks so much for your help. Appreciate it. Cheers!